# Vue: Radio does not update its value when data changes asynchronously

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I do not understand why my new code does not work. I was able to extract a [minimum reproducible case](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-noyce-sldc7?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue). When the `created()` sets a data synchronously, it works well and an article radio is displayed. When I surround it with timeout, then the blog stays selected. Vue 2.6.12

The bug in this code has been fixed, but this was not the cause for my troubles because my real code is different. My problem is that the radio button is not checked when it should be after the reactive data is changed.

```
<Radio
  v-model="type"
  identifier="article"
  class="pl-3"
  label="article"
  name="type"
/>
<Radio
  v-model="type"
  identifier="blog"
  class="pl-3"
  label="blog"
  name="type"
/>
<div>Selected {{ type }}</div>

  data() {
    return {
      type: "blog",
    };
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      this.type = "article";
      console.log(this.type);
    }, 800);
  },
```

This makes my head explode because a similar code in different component works well.

**UPDATE:**

my original code, that does not work, is

```
computed: {
  blog() {
    return this.$store.getters.BLOG;
  },
},
watch: {
 blog() {
  this.type = (this.blog.info.editorial) ? 'article' : 'blog';
 },

created() {
  this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_BLOG', { slug: this.slug });
},
```

Relevant source code:

- https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/234_editorial_team/spa/src/views/item/WriteBlog.vue
- https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/234_editorial_team/spa/src/components/atoms/Radio.vue
- https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/234_editorial_team/spa/src/modules/vuex/items.js

Comment: Joseph's answer is correct. Find on Google difference between arrow and regular functions. It's pretty important.

Comment: Well, that was too simplified sandbox. I have added the real non working code.

Comment: Well you have watch and computed  blog, you should pick one. I doubt it can work like this.

Comment: Actually it does work. All properties including the type are initialized. I can see that with console.log and in Vue developer extension. My problem is that Radio ignores the change. Like it was not reactive.

Comment: I am not saying it won't work. I am saying I doubt it will work properly.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed that MVP arrow function and the problem is still there. The property value is changed but the radio is not checked.

Comment: If you have computed method you need to set setter.

Comment: Please reload the sandbox. There is no computed property and it behaves the same way.

Comment: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-radio I guess that's a problem with bootstrap vue. You need to pass "options" prop. The vue part works. It's the bootstrap part that doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `selected` property in `Radio.vue` is only set equal to `value` in the `created()` hook. When the `setTimeout()` occurs in the parent component, `Radio.vue`'s `v-model` property is changed, which updates its `value` property, but its `selected` property is not automatically updated to match.

The solution is to replace the `created()` hook change with a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) on `value` that updates `selected`:

```js
// Radio.vue
export default {
  created() {
    // ⛔️ Remove this
    //if (this.value) {
    //  this.selected = this.value
    //}
  },

  watch: {
    value: {
      handler(value) {
        this.selected = value
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/updating-radio-button-value-through-v-model-02ucy?file=/src/components/Radio.vue:482-603)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to change your function to an arrow function because it isn't point your data like this

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.type = "article";
      console.log(this.type);
}, 800);
```

Comment: the watch only work with the attributes that exists in your `data` not a computed property

Comment: Actually it does. All properties including types are initialized. I can see the with console.log and with Vue developer extension. The problem I do have is that Radio ignores the change. Like it was not reactive.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your original code does not set the `type` in vue's data function, so it will not reactive when you assign `this.type` to a new value.

Manage state in a form is complicated, check out this library: https://github.com/vue-formily/formily and maybe it helps you easier to work with form, it will let you separate the form definition from vue component that makes it reusable, and it will manage the state for you...

Here is a small demo for your problem: https://codepen.io/hqnan/pen/YzQbxxo